# check if a list of words from a column is used in sentences in other columns

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column(A) with cells of words where I want to highlight words that are used in other Columns containing sentences not single words. How is this possible?

With conditional formatting and a custom formula

`=regexmatch(B1, join("|", filter($A:$A, len($A:$A))))`

it worked that the cells in Column B or C where highlighted whenever they used a word from the cells of column A, but I need it the other way around.

**Cells in column A should be highlighted whenever words from there are used in sentences in Column B or C**

In this example, Column A contains the words and the words should be highlighted if they are used in Sentences in all rows of Column B or C.

Column A:

```
Sausage
Wiener
Brat
```

Column B:

```
I like Sausage
I don't like Steaks
```

Column C:

```
I like Brat
```

Here is my public Spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ARDvwRJAPG4uXL-IyT4Qv3P0RQMFDj4OviM3GKK5Blg/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=AND(LEN(A2),SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(FIND(A2,$B$2:$E$3))))
```

Apply to:

```
A2:A
```

Comment: That works perfect! Thanks! Is it possible to make it case-insensitive as well?

Answer (score 1):

I believe, this *Custom Formula* for the range `B2:B1000` should work:

`=AND(LEN(A2),SUM(ArrayFormula(--REGEXMATCH(B2:E2,A2)))>0)`

> 1. Select the cells you want to format.
> 2. Click Format and then Conditional formatting.
> 3. Under the "Format cells if" drop-down menu, click Custom formula is.
> 4. Click formula and add the formula
> 5. Click Done.

[Instructions](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en#)

Notes:

- Check `LEN(A2)` to skip empty values
- `ArrayFormula(--REGEXMATCH(B2:E2,A2))` will return all matches with [RegexExtract](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en). Double minus `--` is to convert boolean `true` to 1, and `false` to 0.
- second condition `SUM` gives 1 and more if at least one match was found.

Comment: Many thanks, but with this formula it only works if the words are in the same row. i.e. "Brat"(sitting in A4) only gets highlighted if the sentence "I like Brat" in Column C is in C4 not when it is in C5,C2 or C1.